# How can we add fields from google Apps into google forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I'm looking for a way to 'pre fill' a google form with specific data from google apps . As you may know, when the user login to the form, it retrieves it's user name, so how can i put the other known fields (email, phone, department) into google form?

Comment: You can't pre-fill an already loaded form.  You can pre-fill a form, then open the form pre-filled, but you can't dynamically change input values after the form is loaded.  So, what you're asking for isn't "pre-fill" I don't think.  There would need to be another step in between getting the user email and opening the form with the correct information.  So, it would be a multi-step process.  That's your only option.  For example, constructing a pre-filled URL with Apps Script, emailing the pre-filled URL in a link to the user, then the user clicks on the link in the email to open the pre-filled

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks Sandy, I need only to show these fields (the user won't change them)

Comment: @SandyGood solid answer ! 
I had same issue before and built a form from scratch. It's kinda long but it will give you more flexibility

Comment: I'm willing to learn & will be patient in applying @niwox..but can you tell me how??

Comment: On the ui part : a simple form with fields needed  
On server side : functions to retreive needed informations and either return them using function or using templated html.  
If it doesn't make sens I can try to make you a simple example. Are you familiar with AngularJs basics ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to build your own form
**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
      .setTitle('MyTitle')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function getEmail(){
  return Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
}

function test(){
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      email: <br>
      <input name="firstname" id="email">
      <br>
      name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
      <button> send </button>
</form>

<script>
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getEmail();

function onSuccess(email){
  var elem = document.getElementById("email");
  elem.value = email;
}

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @niwox..I've tried both on script editor & on testing getting this :
Script function not found: doGet
How will be able to deploy it?

Comment: make sure to run the function getEmail from the script to authorize it